# Calculating frequency of password hashes efficiently in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hash, group-by, count, frequency

For my bachelor thesis I have to analyze a password leak and I have a table with 2 colums *MEMBER_EMAIL* and *MEMBER_HASH*

**I want to calculate the frequency of each hash *efficiently***

So that the output looks like:

```
Hash    | Amount
----------------
2e3f..  | 345
2f2e..  | 288
b2be..  | 189
```

My query until now was straight forward:

```
SELECT MEMBER_HASH AS hashed, count(*) AS amount 
FROM thesis.fulllist 
GROUP BY hashed 
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

While it works fine for smaller tables, i have problems computing the query on the whole list (112 mio. entries), where it takes me over 2 days, ending in a weird connection timeout error even if my settings regarding that are fine.

So I wonder if there is a better way to calculate (as i can't really think of any), would appreciate any help!

Comment: GROUP BY can make use of indexes, is `hashed` indexed?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, only the combination of both colums and MEMBER_EMAIL was indexed, whoops! Gotta give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can't be optimized as it's quite simple. The only way I think to improve the way the query is executed is to index the "MEMBER_HASH".

This is how you can do it :

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `hashed` (`MEMBER_HASH`);
```

Comment: Thought so! I give it a try (as somehow i don't have it indexed yet), will report back! Thanks so far.

Comment: Seemed like it worked perfectly! Now i just need 30 min instead of the 2 days, thanks a lot!